# How to display Model object properties in razor view VB.net

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, linq, razor

I'm working with ASP MVC 4 VB.net

I have a model:

```vb
Public Class ProdSearchModel

    Class returnedProduct

        Property advertiser_id
        Property advertiser_name
        Property advertiser_category
        Property buy_url
        Property currency
        Property description
        Property image_url
        Property name
        Property price
        Property sale_price

    End Class

    Public Property query As String
    Public Property returnedXML As XElement
    Public Property xmlString As String
    Public Property listOfProducts = New List(Of returnedProduct)

    Sub getXML()

                Using client As New WebClient

               ' Download data as byte array.
                Dim arr = client.DownloadString("https://remoteserver.com/product-search?keywords=" & System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(query))

                returnedXML = XElement.Parse(arr)

                For Each product In returnedXML...<product>
                    Dim currentProduct As New returnedProduct

                currentProduct.advertiser_id = product...<advertiser-id>
                currentProduct.advertiser_name = product...<advertiser-name>
                currentProduct.advertiser_category = product...<advertiser-category>
                currentProduct.buy_url = product...<buy-url>
                currentProduct.currency = product...<currency>
                currentProduct.description = product...<description>
                currentProduct.image_url = product...<image-url>
                currentProduct.name = product...<name>
                currentProduct.price = product...<price>
                currentProduct.sale_price = product...<sale-price>

                listOfProducts.add(currentProduct)
            Next

        End Using

    End Sub


End Class
```

This pulls down some XML

```xml
<advertiser-id>531450</advertiser-id> 
<advertiser-name>Cell Phone Shop</advertiser-name> ...
```

Which is all fine...

My controller looks like this:

```vb
Public Class ProdSearchController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    '
    ' GET: /ProdSearch

    Function Index(query As String) As ActionResult

        Dim model As New ProdSearchModel With {.query = query}
        'model.returnedXML will have the response
        model.getXML()

        Return View(model)
    End Function

End Class
```

And the view looks like this:

```html
@ModelType matrix.ProdSearchModel 
@Code
    Layout = Nothing

End Code

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    @For Each product In Model.listOfProducts

    @product.advertiser_category

    Next

   <hr />

        @*Html.Raw(Model.returnedXML)   *@

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If I dump the XML "Model.returnedXML" it is all there.

But how do I reference each item in the "listOfProducts"?

Also there is no intelisense on the @product:

[image]

I just have .ToString etc, rather than the actually properties, although if I run in debug mode I can see the datastructure is there.

[image]

At the moment I just get d__aSystem.Xml.Linq.XContainer+d__aSystem.Xml.Linq.XContainer+>  each time I should see e.g. the product code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring your property `listOfProducts` in your class `ProdSearchModel`, you are not setting the type of the property:

```
Public Property listOfProducts = New List(Of returnedProduct)
```

That means your property will be of type `Object`, so Intellisense will not be able to help you. At runtime it will be assigned a `List(Of returnedProduct)`, which is what you see when setting a break point in your view.

You should set the type of your property, so the compiler and Intellisense know about it:

```
Public Property listOfProducts As List(Of returnedProduct) = New List(Of returnedProduct)
```

There are also some problems with your `returnedProduct` class and the way you are reading from the Xml. I suggest you to have a quick look at [this msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384974.aspx)

For retrieving the node values you can either cast the node as the desired simple type or access its value property. (As described in the [msdn here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387049.aspx)).
Start by defining the property types in your `returnedProduct` class, something like the following (I am guessing the types, use the ones that make most sense for you):

```
Class returnedProduct
    Property advertiser_id As Integer
    Property advertiser_name As String
    Property advertiser_category As String
    Property buy_url As String
    Property currency As String
    Property description As String
    Property image_url As String
    Property name As String
    Property price As Decimal
    Property sale_price As Decimal
End Class
```

Then populate the properties from the nodes, for example using the Value property. As the properties are not of type `Object`, the values will be nicely converted into the expected types:

```
currentProduct.advertiser_id = product...<advertiser-id>.Value
currentProduct.advertiser_name = product...<advertiser-name>.Value
currentProduct.advertiser_category = product...<advertiser-category>.Value
currentProduct.buy_url = product...<buy-url>.Value
currentProduct.currency = product...<currency>.Value
currentProduct.description = product...<description>.Value
currentProduct.image_url = product...<image-url>.Value
currentProduct.name = product...<name>.Value
currentProduct.price = product...<price>.Value
currentProduct.sale_price = product...<sale-price>.Value
```

With the previous changes you should get Intellisense working in your view (Assuming the `@ModelType` declaration is correct in the view). You should also get the proper output now that the properties in `returnedProduct` are correctly defined and populated.

- Previously you had them as `Object` and were incorrectly populated with Linq.Xml objects for each node, instead of the node values. Razor was calling `ToString` method on each property, which returned the runtime type name.

For example you can create a very simple view rendering a table with some of the product fields:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>advertiser_id</th>
            <th>advertiser_name</th>
            <th>advertiser_category</th>
            <th>buy_url</th>
            <th>currency</th>
            <th>price</th>
            <th>description</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
    <tbody>
    @For Each product In Model.listOfProducts
        @<tr>
            <td>@product.advertiser_id</td>
            <td>@product.advertiser_name</td>
            <td>@product.advertiser_category</td>
            <td>@product.buy_url</td>
            <td>@product.currency</td>
            <td>@product.price</td>
            <td>@product.description</td>
        </tr>
    Next
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr />
<pre>
@Model.returnedXML
</pre>
```

Hope it helps!